# Rendering an image on a PDF page

Tags: c++, image, pdf

I am trying to create and render an image in a PDF page. I am using the [PDEImageCreate](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/pdfl_sdk/9/PDFL_SDK9_HTMLHelp/API_References/Acrobat_API_Reference/PDFEdit_Layer/PDEImage.html#PDEImageCreate626()) API to create a `PDEImage` object and later set this object in the `PDEContent` of the `PDPage`.

But, I am unable to render proper image on the page. I am sending raw data as input and using the `DeviceRGB` color space. Here's a snapshot of the code I am using:

```
unsigned char* mImageDataBuffer;    
mImageDataBuffer = (unsigned char*)ASmalloc((ASSize_t)30000);

imageAttrs.bitsPerComponent = 8;
imageAttrs.flags = kPDEImageIsMask;
imageAttrs.width = 100;
imageAttrs.height = 100;
imageAttrs.intent = ASAtomNull;

imageMatrix.a = ASFloatToFixed(500.0);
imageMatrix.b = fixedZero;
imageMatrix.c = fixedZero;
imageMatrix.d = ASFloatToFixed(500.0);
imageMatrix.h = fixedZero;
imageMatrix.v = fixedZero;

for (int i = 0; i < 30000;)
{
    mImageDataBuffer[i++] = 0x00;
    mImageDataBuffer[i++] = 0x00;
    mImageDataBuffer[i++] = 0x0f;
}

PDEColorValueP pdeColorValue = (PDEColorValueP)ASmalloc(sizeof(PDEColorValue));
memset(pdeColorValue, 0, sizeof(PDEColorValue));
pdeColorValue->color[0] = FloatToASFixed(255.0f);
pdeColorValue->color[1] = FloatToASFixed(0.0f);
pdeColorValue->color[2] = FloatToASFixed(0.0f);

pdeImage = PDEImageCreate(&imageAttrs, (Uns32)sizeof(imageAttrs), &imageMatrix, 0, PDEColorSpaceCreateFromName(ASAtomFromString("DeviceRGB")),
    pdeColorValue, NULL, 0, mImageDataBuffer, 0);
```

There are primarily two problems I am unable to figure out a reason for-

1. I tried to put random values in the mImageDataBuffer and if anything was rendered on the page, it's always black and white.
2. If one of the bytes of the data buffer is `0x00`, then Acrobat throws an error message if rest of the bytes are non-zero.

I am sure that I am missing out something important. Could someone point me towards the right direction?

Comment: Why the image a mask? If there are no exception, maybe the image is fine but the error comes with the rest of how you define the PDF. For exampe, XObject images need to be rendered using the Do operator.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the last parameter be the size of `mImageDataBuffer`?  e.g.:

```cpp
pdeImage = PDEImageCreate(&imageAttrs, (Uns32)sizeof(imageAttrs), &imageMatrix, 0,       PDEColorSpaceCreateFromName(ASAtomFromString("DeviceRGB")),
pdeColorValue, NULL, 0, mImageDataBuffer, 30000);
```